# Preserve query parameters when S3 redirects /dir to /dir/

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-router

I have a React Single Page App (SPA) backed by Cloudfront/S3. I have an S3 bucket `/welcome/` and redirect client side to `/welcome/new`. I'm having problems preserving query parameters in both situations (this is a requirement). Here's how I'd like requests to be routed:

`/welcome?test=true` -> `/welcome/new/?test=true`

`/welcome/?test=true` -> `/welcome/new/?test=true`

There is an issue with the first request. Because `welcome` is an S3 directory, S3 302's `/welcome` to `/welcome/`, and I lose query parameters.

From [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html):

`However, if you exclude the trailing slash from the preceding URL, Amazon S3 first looks for an object photos in the bucket. If the photos object is not found, then it searches for an index document, photos/index.html. If that document is found, Amazon S3 returns a 302 Found message and points to the photos/ key. For subsequent requests to photos/, Amazon S3 returns photos/index.html. If the index document is not found, Amazon S3 returns an error.`

One solution I thought of was to run Lambda@Edge code and have requests to Cloudfront redirected with query parameters preserved in both cases. Is this a good approach? I'm worried about any gotchas since I'm changing default S3 routing behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure that I have a good understanding of your request. Is there a reason for not implementing this URL change client-side? If there is, I will like to suggest using API Gateway as an S3 proxy https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html. You can this way take advantage of Cloudfront caching in front of the API Gateway.

Comment: Do you want to preserve the react routes even someone reloads the route in browser or directly got to a route path? If so refer https://codeburst.io/deploying-angular-react-apps-in-aws-ec55a4fb7446

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with/solvable by React routing. The request query params are stripped by S3, prior to retrieving the index.html. You lose the params before client-side routing kicks in.